# Is it possible to call custom function with setTimeout Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to stop the execution of my code by 2 seconds so that all the on going animation can get finished. I am trying to call a function using setTimeout in Node.js

what I am doing in my code :

```
this.userActivity = function(a,b,side){
     //some code of mine
     setTimeout(this.doTheMagicIfPossible(this.scoringPossible),2000);
}

this. doTheMagicIfPossible = function(passedValue){
     console.log("printing it out after 2 seconds"+passedValue);
}
```

But, execution is not getting stopped for 2 seconds.

If I do like this:

```
setTimeout(this.doTheMagicIfPossible,2000,this.scoringPossible);
```

Execution is getting stopped by 2 seconds but function is not getting this.scoringPossible, it's undefined in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. You aren't seeing execution stopping for 2 seconds, because you are actually calling `doTheMagicIfPossible` from inside your `setTimeout` call.

If you want to pass parameters to the callback passed to `setTimeout`, you need to pass in a function taking no arguments that provides the correct arguments to your callback. Javascript provides the function [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) in `Function`'s prototype to do just this, for example:

```
setTimeout(this.doTheMagicIfPossible.bind(this, this.scoringPossible),2000);
```

Here, `bind` creates a new function, taking no arguments, which when called will call `doTheMagicIfPossible` with `this` set to the same `this`, and `this.scoringPossible` as the first argument.

Comment: With less magic: `var me = this; setTimeout( function(){ me.doTheMagicIfPossible(me.scoringPossible) }, 2000 );` where `me` is used to refer to `this` later on, where it may have changed.